# Min dates from group by postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, min, distinct-on

I have table with data:

```
create table measure_app_scalemeasurement (
  store_code text,
  certificate_id text,
  audit_ending date);
insert into measure_app_scalemeasurement values
('K010','vwv',  '10.12.2023'),
('K010','cert1','12.12.2023'),
('K054','vwv',  '14.12.2023'),
('K054','cert1','20.01.2024');
```

I want to select min `audit_ending` date for each market `store_code`, also getting its corresponding `cert_id`

Here's a query I tried

```
select store_code, certificate_id, min(audit_ending) from measure_app_scalemeasurement
group by store_code, certificate_id
```

[image: pic1]

But it is giving *all* markets `store_code`, and this query:

```
select distinct on (store_code) store_code, certificate_id, min(audit_ending) from measure_app_scalemeasurement
group by store_code, certificate_id
```

[image: pic2]

it gave min date for market K010, but did not for market K054. For K054 it is giving max date.

I want to get first min date by markets with its certificate id
like this:

| store_code | certificate_id | audit_ending |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K010 | vwv | 10.12.2023 |
| K054 | vwv | 20.01.2024 |

Comment: Please paste the code as text, not pictures.

Comment: That tiny image text is hard to read on my small laptop screen. And I can't copy-and-paste from images.

Comment: First, post the code and results as text. Images can't be copied and tested. Second, clarify what you want. It seems like you want to get the earliest certificate per market by date.

Comment: And *please* use the same column names in the queries. There's no `audit_ending` in the question itself and no `date` in the images

Comment: I have corrected all parts that u asked guys, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) was almost right: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/y10dN_rS)

```
select distinct on(store_code) store_code, certificate_id, audit_ending
from measure_app_scalemeasurement
order by store_code, audit_ending;
```

| store_code | certificate_id | audit_ending |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K010 | vwv | 2023-12-10 |
| K054 | vwv | 2023-12-14 |

You just needed a matching `order by` so that for each `store_code` it only keeps the earliest (min) date.

Comment: Yes, it was, thanks for help

Comment: A regular `distinct on` is also simpler and faster than emulating it through the use of `row_number()over()`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PFh58ndN)

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number() + filter rn=1:

```
select market,  certificate_id,   date
from 
(
select market,  certificate_id,   date,
       row_number() over(partition by market order by date) rn
  from mytable
) s 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: The `from` clause is missing from the inner query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using window function `row_number()` to order records by audit_ending per market.

You can also use `rank()` instead of `row_number()` if you have ties and you want to return them all (exemple a market with same two lowest *audit_ending* ).

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by market order by audit_ending) as rn
  from mytable
) as s
where rn = 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/e8MM5db2)